# Communicate correct Java version to Hadoop

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

I have basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625516/java-runtime-error-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-mi) problem, except that when I go to the folder where hadoop is installed, there is no `hadoop/config`, so I don't know where to look for `hadoop-env.sh`. How can I get Hadoop to look for my up-to-data Java rather than my mandatory OSX legacy Java?

Comment: Where exactly is hadoop installed? What is inside hadoop directory?

Comment: Homebrew installed Hadoop in `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop`. The only thing inside is a directory `2.7.1`. Within that, I found the hadoop-env file at `usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`.

Comment: So, problem resolved?

Comment: Yes, problem resolved.

Comment: Good!. If the current answers where not helpful, you should write your own solution and accept it, this is important for other users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried hadoop-2.7.2 locally, in my experience, you can specify your configuration directory by environment `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`.

To put it simple, you can just `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR` before you start HDFS by `start-dfs.sh`. At this point, you can add your own `JAVA_HOME` at `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hadoop-env.sh`. By the way, `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` usually points to a directory copy from the `hadoop` release. For example, in `hadoop-2.7.2` you can just copy `hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/` and update the necessary configuration and specify it as your own `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`.

Thanks for [eric_kernfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3371472/eric-kernfeld)'s improvement:

> UPDATE: since OP used a Homebrew installation, there were multiple
>   directories named `hadoop`, and OP had to go through
>   `<version>/libexec/etc/hadoop.`

At the end, `hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/`(please use your own version instead of `2.7.2`) is the default `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`, which means you can just update `hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` as you wish.

However, there might be some difference if your hadoop release early than 2.x.x.

Comment: Since there are multiple directories named `hadoop`, and the `etc` helped me find the right one, I am accepting this answer. But, I had to go through `<version>/libexec/etc/hadoop`, not `<version>/etc/hadoop` as you indicate. May I edit your answer to include this?

Comment: I'm so appreciate that you could improve it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I've ignored the fact that you ware not using the tarball of hadoop release but from the operating system source repository. In my tries, I've only downloaded the tarball from official [site](http://apache.fayea.com/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz) and extract it and update the necessary environment. In my circumstance, it's actually in directory `hadoop-x.x.x/etc/hadoop`. I'm sorry for not specifying it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

For Hadoop 2+, the `hadoop-env.sh` file should be directly in `hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`.

If the file not exist, you could create it, and put inside:

```
export JAVA_HOME={your java home path}
```